# JFreeChart hide behind other one

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jfreechart

I was trying to build UI in IntelliJ but it was hard so I tried to build it in Eclipse. Now UI looks little better but still poor. One of chart (the cener one) should be biger and second one on south should be smaller but flat and long. I tried to use preffered size or validate or repaint but still nothing. How to anchor them to side borders, and avoid to cover them self?

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{

private JPanel contentPane;

private XYSeries daneXYSciezki;
private XYSeries daneXYWys;

private final XYSeriesCollection wykCenter;
private final XYSeriesCollection wykSouth;

public MainWindow(){
   setTitle("ParserGPS");
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setBounds(100, 100, 880, 640);
   contentPane = new JPanel();
   contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
   setContentPane(contentPane);
   contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

   JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
   FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panelNorth.getLayout();
   flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
   contentPane.add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

   JButton btnWczytajPlik = new JButton("Wczytaj plik");
   panelNorth.add(btnWczytajPlik);

   JLabel lblOdlego = new JLabel("Odległość:");
   panelNorth.add(lblOdlego);

   JLabel lblm = new JLabel("0m");
   panelNorth.add(lblm);

   JLabel lblCzas = new JLabel("Czas:");
   panelNorth.add(lblCzas);

   JLabel label = new JLabel("00:00:00");
   panelNorth.add(label);

   JLabel lblPrdko = new JLabel("Prędkość:");
   panelNorth.add(lblPrdko);

   JLabel lblkmh = new JLabel("0km/h");
   panelNorth.add(lblkmh);

   JLabel lblNrSat = new JLabel("Nr sat:");
   panelNorth.add(lblNrSat);

   JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("0");
   panelNorth.add(label_1);

   JLabel lblGga = new JLabel("GGA:");
   lblGga.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
   panelNorth.add(lblGga);

   JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("0/0");
   panelNorth.add(label_2);

   JLabel lblGsa = new JLabel("GSA:");
   panelNorth.add(lblGsa);

   JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("0/0");
   panelNorth.add(label_3);

   JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("RMC:");
   panelNorth.add(lblNewLabel);

   JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("0/0");
   panelNorth.add(label_4);

   JLabel lblGll = new JLabel("GLL:");
   panelNorth.add(lblGll);

   JLabel label_5 = new JLabel("0/0");
   panelNorth.add(label_5);

   JLabel lblVtg = new JLabel("VTG:");
   panelNorth.add(lblVtg);

   JLabel label_6 = new JLabel("0/0");
   panelNorth.add(label_6);

   JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel();
   contentPane.add(jpCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   jpCenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(785, 440));

   JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel();
   FlowLayout flowLayout_1 = (FlowLayout) jpSouth.getLayout();
   flowLayout_1.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
   contentPane.add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

   this.daneXYSciezki = new XYSeries("Trasa", false);
   wykCenter = new XYSeriesCollection(this.daneXYSciezki);
   final JFreeChart jfcWykCenter = createChart(wykCenter);
   final ChartPanel jfcPanelCenter = new ChartPanel(jfcWykCenter);
   jpCenter.add(jfcPanelCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);

   this.daneXYSciezki = new XYSeries("Wysokość", false);
   wykSouth = new XYSeriesCollection(this.daneXYSciezki);
   final JFreeChart jfcWykSouth = createChart(wykSouth);
   final ChartPanel jfcPanelSouth = new ChartPanel(jfcWykSouth);
   jpSouth.add(jfcPanelSouth,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   repaint();
   revalidate();
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "",
                "Szerokość",
                "Długość",
                dataset);
        final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        yAxis.setAutoRange(true);
        customizeChart(result);
        return result;
    }

    private void customizeChart(JFreeChart chart) {
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer;
        renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, true);
        renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, true);
        renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

[image: Window I created]

After @m.cekiera advices

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
private JPanel contentPane;

private XYSeries daneXYSciezki;
private XYSeries daneXYWys;

private final XYSeriesCollection wykCenter;
private final XYSeriesCollection wykSouth;

public MainWindow(){
    setTitle("ParserGPS");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 880, 640);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panelNorth.getLayout();
    flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    contentPane.add(panelNorth,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JButton btnWczytajPlik = new JButton("Wczytaj plik");
    panelNorth.add(btnWczytajPlik);

    JLabel lblOdlego = new JLabel("Odległość:");
    panelNorth.add(lblOdlego);

    JLabel lblm = new JLabel("0m");
    panelNorth.add(lblm);

    JLabel lblCzas = new JLabel("Czas:");
    panelNorth.add(lblCzas);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("00:00:00");
    panelNorth.add(label);

    JLabel lblPrdko = new JLabel("Prędkość:");
    panelNorth.add(lblPrdko);

    JLabel lblkmh = new JLabel("0km/h");
    panelNorth.add(lblkmh);

    JLabel lblNrSat = new JLabel("Nr sat:");
    panelNorth.add(lblNrSat);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("0");
    panelNorth.add(label_1);

    JLabel lblGga = new JLabel("GGA:");
    //lblGga.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panelNorth.add(lblGga);

    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("0/0");
    panelNorth.add(label_2);

    JLabel lblGsa = new JLabel("GSA:");
    panelNorth.add(lblGsa);

    JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("0/0");
    panelNorth.add(label_3);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("RMC:");
    panelNorth.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("0/0");
    panelNorth.add(label_4);

    JLabel lblGll = new JLabel("GLL:");
    panelNorth.add(lblGll);

    JLabel label_5 = new JLabel("0/0");
    panelNorth.add(label_5);

    JLabel lblVtg = new JLabel("VTG:");
    panelNorth.add(lblVtg);

    JLabel label_6 = new JLabel("0/0");
    panelNorth.add(label_6);

    JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.add(jpCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //jpCenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(785, 440));

    JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    //FlowLayout flowLayout_1 = (FlowLayout) jpSouth.getLayout();
   // flowLayout_1.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
    contentPane.add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.daneXYSciezki = new XYSeries("Trasa", false);
    wykCenter = new XYSeriesCollection(this.daneXYSciezki);
    final JFreeChart jfcWykCenter = createChart(wykCenter);
    final ChartPanel jfcPanelCenter = new ChartPanel(jfcWykCenter);
    jpCenter.add(jfcPanelCenter,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.daneXYSciezki = new XYSeries("Wysokość", false);
    wykSouth = new XYSeriesCollection(this.daneXYSciezki);
    final JFreeChart jfcWykSouth = createChart(wykSouth);
    final ChartPanel jfcPanelSouth = new ChartPanel(jfcWykSouth);
    jpCenter.add(jfcPanelSouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

...
}
```

[image: after 3rd correct]

Answer (score 2):

As your code is not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I could not run it with changes, but I think your problem is bad layout settings. For example, you create a new `JPanel`:

```
JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel();
FlowLayout flowLayout_1 = (FlowLayout) jpSouth.getLayout();
flowLayout_1.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
```

You are aware that it is using `FlowLayout` by defaul, by later you use:

```
jpSouth.add(jfcPanelSouth,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

but you never change layout to `BorderLayout`. You cannot mix layout of one particular container. But this is not what couse you problem directly.

Your `BorderLayout.SOUTH` area stretch horizontally, to fit components inside, and `BorderLayout.CENTER` takes all spece left(or not). This is how those parts of `BorderLayout` works. So you can change where you put particular components, or change layout at all.

I suggest to try with:

```
JPanel jpCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
...
jpCenter.add(jfcPanelCenter,BorderLayout.NORTH);
...
jpCenter.add(jfcPanelSouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH); //not to contentPane!
```

this will change an arrangement. However I am not sure, is it what you want. If not, try with different layout, for example `BoxLayout`.
Also I would rather use `pack()` and set size of components, than `setBounds` on a countainer.

You can also use GUI builders, like Netbeans IDE GUI Builder if you want to create GUI but don't care how.

Comment: Your advices was very helpful. I am close to resolve my problem after I add your suggest. Only one thing that I can't figure out. Why center panel now is wide and flat, south panel is bigger. I wanted south panel to be wide and flat and center panel to be bigger and main chart

Comment: @GarryMoveOut I think it is the same problem as before, you still add `jpCenter` to `contentPane` center, so it will change size to fit spece left. Then you add `jpSouth` to contentPane SOUTH part - so again it vertically expand. Try to put both: **`jfcPanelCenter`** into **NORTH** position, and **`jfcPanelSouth`** into **SOUTH** position of **`jpCenter's  BorderLayout`**.

Comment: I wrong understood you earlier. I correct code as you suggest me. Its almost good. But some of `jfcPanelSouth` is behind `jfcPalenCenter`

Comment: @GarryMoveOut mayby try with JFrame.pack()